# PHP prevent a variable passed via query string, but allow the same variable to be passed via apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess `mod_rewrite` to convert a nice URL, and using a php variable `page` to send the url portion to `index.php` where rest of the processing is done.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now, if some malicious user passes the `page` variable via query string, it gets accepted. For example, if the user calls `http://mysite.com/login?page=registration` instead of loading the `login` page, user specified `registration` page gets loaded.

Any idea how to fix it within the `htaccess` file?

Comment: just remove the `QSA` in the mod rewrite, this will then disregard any query string passed... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: I still need other queries passed, just want to ignore the page='' portion of the query string. So, cannot turn QSA off

Comment: Why don't you read `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead to find out what real page was requested? "malicious user" will not be able to mess with this like that -- unless he has his code already executing on a server.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked for answers for the same thing myself and I'm pretty sure there is no solution to it. The only solution I've come up with is to replace `page` with some arbitrary "key" instead, like `98198bs129387b13`. Thus, they would have to know the key. But make no mistake, this is security through obscurity... and having proper checks in index.php is still necessary (and it is regardless).

Comment: +1 for the key method *and* the notion that it's still just security through obscurity

Comment: Looks like a solution, but how do I replace `page` by some random key within `.htaccess` ? Would you please provide sample code?

Comment: @giga I mean to literally replace `page` with some random key... aka, **rename** `page` to `98198bs129387b13`... and do `$page = $_GET['98198bs129387b13']` in index.php or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> if the user calls http://mysite.com/login?page=registration instead of loading the login page, user specified registration page gets loaded.

You can't fix this using mod_rewrite - after all, what's to stop the attacker from entering

```
domain.com/registration
```

instead?

You need to make sure that unauthorized users can *never* access pages they're not supposed to access.

Comment: I don't want to prevent access to registration ... just wondering if some malicious 'module' (the project is open-source & user contributed codes can be installed) append all generated urls with some page=blah query!